# Sort before querying

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to run a sort on a Mongo collection before running the filtering query? I have older code in which I was using a method of getting a random result from the database by having a field which was a random float between 0 and 1, then querying with `findOne` to get the first document with a value greater than a random float generated at that time. The sample set was small, so didn't notice a problem at the time, but recently noticed that with one query, I was almost always getting the same value. The "first" document had a random > .9, so nearly every query matched it first.

I realized, for this solution to work, I need to sort by random, then find the first value greater than my random. As I understand it, this isn't as necessary a solution as in the past, as `$sample` exists as of 3.2, but I figure learning how I could do this would be good? Plus, my understanding is that `$sample` can return the same document multiple times (where N > 1 obviously, so not directly applicable to my question).

So for example, the following data:

```
> db.links.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("553c072bc87652a80e00002a"), "random" : 0.9162904409691691 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("553c3332c87652c80700002a"), "random" : 0.00427396921440959 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("553c3c5cc87652a80e00002b"), "random" : 0.2409569111187011 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("553c3c66c876521c10000029"), "random" : 0.35101076657883823 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("553c3c6ec87652200700002e"), "random" : 0.3234482416883111 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("553c68d5c87652a80e00002c"), "random" : 0.5221220930106938 }
```

Any attempt to run `db.mycollection.findOne({'random': {'$gte': x}})` where x is any value up to .91 always return the first object (_id 553c072). Anything greater returns nothing. If I could sort by the `random` value in ascending order then filter, it would keep searching until it found the correct value.

Comment: Can you please add some sample documents and query which gives you incorrect results?

Comment: Sorry about that, sample data added.

Comment: I don't think that mixing real data with fields holding random values is a good idea. Consider to use $sample and remove this field from your documents

Comment: I do intend on dropping this solution now that I've learned about `$sample` (found it in the process of trying to figure out this problem), but I was hoping to learn how to implement this for future use in other scenarios, such as wanting to get the first 5 documents in alphabetic order starting with a letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you to drop your custom solution and simply switch to using the MongoDB built-in [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) stage which will return a random result from your collection.

**EDIT** based on your comment:

Here's how you can do what you originally asked for:

```
db.links.find({ "random": { $gte: /* put your value here */ } })
.sort({ "random": 1 /* sort by "random" field in ascending order */ })
.limit(1)
```

You can, but don't need to use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), too:

```
db.links.aggregate({
    $match: {
        "random": {
            $gte: /* put your value here */ // filter the collection
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "random": 1 // sort by "random" field in ascending order
    }
}, {
    $limit: 1 // return only the first element
})
```

Comment: I do intend on dropping this solution now that I've learned about `$sample` (found it in the process of trying to figure out this problem), but I was hoping to learn how to implement this for future use in other scenarios, such as wanting to get the first 5 documents in alphabetic order starting with a letter.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at aggregate previously, but I didn't think about it like that: get ALL values greater than my value, and then only return one in the ordered set. I should be able to do this without aggregate as well, right?